My websocket connection is dropping with Ethers.js
I establish a websocket connection with Ethers WebsocketProvider but after a few minutes the connection drops. I get the error status but it doesn't show as an error, just no data.
I tried to write the heartbeat function myself, but all the solutions were based on old versions of ethers and I am new to the module. I migrated a solution from the internet, I couldn't ping the server directly, but I sent a query asking for the network status. Overall it still didn't work, but this time I'm close, it just needs some editing.
const blockchainListener = async() => {
    try {
        await Promise.all(wss_servers.map(async(rpc) => {
            const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(rpc.server)
        
            const EXPECTED_PONG_BACK = 15000
            const KEEP_ALIVE_CHECK_INTERVAL = 7500
    
            let pingTimeout = null
            let keepAliveInterval = null
    
            provider.websocket.onopen = () => {
                keepAliveInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    const pingMessage = {
                        jsonrpc: "2.0",
                        method: "net_version",
                        params: [],
                        id: 1
                    };
                    provider.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(pingMessage));
                    pingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                        provider.destroy()
                    }, EXPECTED_PONG_BACK)
                }, KEEP_ALIVE_CHECK_INTERVAL)
            }
    
            await provider.on('block', async (new_block_number) => {
                const block = await provider.getBlock(new_block_number, true)

                if(block){
                    await create_home_data(block, rpc.chain, provider)
                    await create_all_transactions_data(block, rpc.chain, provider)
                    await create_all_blocks_data(block, rpc.chain, provider)
                }
            })
    
            provider.websocket.onerror = err => {
                console.error('websocket error', err.message)
                clearInterval(keepAliveInterval)
                clearTimeout(pingTimeout)
                startConnection()
            }
    
            provider.websocket.onmessage = message => {
                console.log(message.data)
                clearInterval(pingTimeout)
            }
        }))
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('blockchainListener error', error.message)
    }
}

